# Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 128 for 'SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried to read an images as png format using conventional neural network in tensorflow. I faced a problem that I cannot deal with label in read data step, so, it gives me an error.

First thing I thought the problem is happened when I create *batch queue and shuffle*.
which was the problem in **tf.train.shuffle_batch** expected 1-D but actually it got shape as 3-D.

I fixed that. and then it gives me another error in **loss function**

The subcode is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksgdqtmxd6fa82o/SVHN.py?dl=0)

the problem is::

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "SVHN.py", line 280, in 
> >         tf.app.run()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
> >     line 48, in run
> >         _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))   File "SVHN.py", line 269, in main
> >         train_op = SVHN_architecture_AND_optimize()   File "SVHN.py", line 203, in SVHN_architecture_AND_optimize
> >         cross_entropy =  tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels
> >     = labels)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py",
> >     line 1742, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
> >         precise_logits, labels, name=name)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py",
> >     line 2418, in _sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
> >         features=features, labels=labels, name=name)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
> >     line 768, in apply_op
> >         op_def=op_def)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> >     line 2338, in create_op
> >         set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> >     line 1719, in set_shapes_for_outputs
> >         shapes = shape_func(op)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> >     line 1669, in call_with_requiring
> >         return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py",
> >     line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
> >         debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py",
> >     line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
> >         raise ValueError(err.message) ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 128 for
> >     'SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> >     (op: 'SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [1,10],
> >     [128].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is because only 1 input image is getting passed to the  `SparseSoftmaxEntropyWithLogits` and not a complete batch. This line is causing the problem:

```
# change your single input `image` to a batch of `images`
images = tf.reshape(images, [-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, depth])
```

Comment: I fixed this error by remove this line and using the images that produce from batch queue to be an input in the first layer. But it still there an problem::    
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape mismatch in tuple component 1. Expected [1], got [1,92,3]

Comment: The new error is the first error appear, it is in tf.train.shuffle_batch

Comment: If there are different issues, open up a new issue thread. I answered for whatever error you have raised here.

Comment: I mean that when I use the (images = tf.reshape(images, [-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, depth])  the error be in SparseSoftmaxEntropyWithLogits ,, but when I remove it, the error be in tf.train.shuffle_batch.... I still do not know how can I solve this problem

Comment: I think the problem is because the shuffle step requested 128, but the  current size is  0,,,, so I can not solve it. I hope that you can understand what I mean, because I cannot speak English very well

Comment: Ok in that case update the second error also... i want to see the complete trace.

Comment: can u print the shape of all the tensors going into shuffle batch?. ex labels.get_shape().as_list()

Comment: This is after reading phase:::
>>> image.get_shape().as_list()
[32, 32, 3]
>>> label.get_shape().as_list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 761, in as_list
    raise ValueError("as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.")
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

Comment: This after distortions step that going to shuffle batch ::::  >>> float_image.get_shape().as_list()
[32, 32, 3]
>>> label.get_shape().as_list()
[1]

Comment: and this after create queue and shuffle:::::   >>> images.get_shape().as_list()
[128, 32, 32, 3]
>>> labels.get_shape().as_list()
[128]

Comment: this values seems fine... the problem mentioned is in the labels. Is there any chance sometimes your labels are wrong in the tfrecords?.

Comment: this is what I thought from the began because that I write in my question I cannot deal with labels,,, do you now how can I deal with labels when I using the (tf.image.decode_png)

Comment: tf.image.decode_png doesnt save labels. U have to save it seperately in the tfrecords file.

Comment: Use this code to convert into tfrecords :https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py .

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort, I will check this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I can't view your code (link doesn't work or the dropbox file isn't public) but based on the error, your labels are the wrong shape. For SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits the labels should be shaped [None,], where None is the batch dimension - i.e. your labels should be integers, not one-hot encoded vectors.

Comment: The link was not shared in dropbox sorry, now it is public

Comment: line 193: logits = tf.nn.softmax(network)  ## normalization
is unnecessary. SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits has the softmax built-in. Your result will be wrong if you apply softmax prior to it as well

Comment: You appear to have a third softmax on line 191: network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax', weights_init='xavier')

Comment: Try printing labels.get_shape() and logits.get_shape() on a line right before your loss function. That should help debug. Tell me here what it prints then.

Comment: I fixed the code based in your hint. and this is the printing::  >>> labels.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(128)])
>>> logits.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(10)])

Comment: That doesn't match up with the error though. You're printing that on the line immediately above cross_entropy?

FYI the other tips have nothing to do with this error. I just noticed the extra softmax and thought I'd tell you since your result (after you fix this error) would be wrong otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the printing is on the line immediately above the cross_entropy... and thank you for your hints because it was wrong to use softmax before SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits.

Comment: I think my problem is in label in the read step,,, do have any idea how to fixed it????